# how to implement softdelete in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a model where I need to soft delete a record and not show them in the find or any other conditions while searching.

I want to retain the model without deleting the record. How to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a `deleted` field with a migration and a scope to filter out any deleted records.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement your own by creating nullable `deleted_at` date-time field in DB.
2. Use one of [these gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Soft_Delete).